# Why can't I have flash_image working?

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode

I've rooted my device (Omega T107) and i cannot install any recovery (tried cyanogenmod adn amon_ra)

When I use flash_image as root it never ends

Screen link:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Uhhh, you're going about this the wrong way.

You do not `adb push` the flash image onto the handset itself then `adb shell` into it and flash from there.

The two reasons being is that

1. From the `adb shell` it cannot "see" the recovery partition and does not know anything about it!
2. There is limited space within the `/data` mount point which could have contributed to the endless stalling...

The correct way to do this is from the PC side, put the handset into fast-boot mode or boot-loader mode, plug in the cable into handset and use the `fastboot flash recovery recovery.img` then reboot the handset via `fastboot reboot`, holding down the volume down key to get into recovery mode.

The windows equivalent of the `fastboot` command would be `fastboot-windows` IIRC.